# Алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла...модификация

Tags: c++

Дан ориентированный взвешенный граф. По его матрице смежности нужно для каждой пары вершин определить, существует ли кратчайший путь между ними или нет.

```
#include <iostream>
const int inf=1E9;
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
 int n,i,j,k,d[100][100];
 scanf("%d",&n);
 for (i=0;i<n;++i)
  for (j=0;j<n;++j)
  {
   scanf("%d",&d[i][j]);
   if (i==j) d[i][j]=min(d[i][j],0);
   if (d[i][j]==1001) d[i][j]=inf;
  }
 for (k=0;k<n;++k)
  for (i=0;i<n;++i)
   for (j=0;j<n;++j)
    if (d[i][k]<inf && d[k][j]<inf) d[i][j]=min(d[i][j],d[i][k]+d[k][j]);
 for (i=0;i<n;++i)
 for (i=0;i<n;++i,printf("\n"))
  for (j=0;j<n;++j)
   if (d[i][j]==inf) printf("NO "); else printf("%d ",d[i][j]);
}
```

А, если между вершинами расстояние < 0 вывести в таблицу число 5. Как это сделать?

Comment: что именно у Вас не получается сделать?
Этот код написали Вы? или по крайней мере разобрались в нем?

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, весь код понятен...как его изменить если у нас в графе есть рёбра отрицательного веса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, у Вас в коде написана лишняя строка по ошибке:

```
for (i=0;i<n;++i)
for (i=0;i<n;++i,printf("\n"))
```

Первая их этих двух.

Во вторых. Ели в графе у нас нет циклов отрицательного веса, то поиск путей в графе у нас не измениться.

Другое дело, если в графе имеется цикл отрицательного веса, тогда можно ходить по нему сколько угодно раз и мы сможем каждый раз уменьшать расстояния до вершин.

Если не ошибаюсь Вам все же необходимо добавить проверку на цикл отрицательного веса, если да, то вот как это делается:
опять перебираем пары вершин (i,j) и промежуточную вершину k, если найдется такое ребро, которое изменит уже посчитаны значения, то нас в графе цикл отрицательного веса.

Почитайте об этом алгоритме вот [тут](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/floyd_warshall_algorithm)

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey, часть кода для проверки и выода в таблицу 5 можно?
я не могу понять как это пеализовать: если найдется такое ребро, которое изменит уже посчитаны значения, то нас в графе цикл отрицательного веса.